# Asp.net mvc route map problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a new control VidController

    `public class VidController : Controller

    {

        public ActionResult GetVids()

        {

            return View();

        }

    }`

Right clicked inside the method and created View with default name GetVids. Now when i try to open ~/Vid/GetVids  there is no page opening...
What i have to set in Global file?

Comment: What do you mean by no page opening, do you get an error or a blank page? If there's an error, what is it, if it's blank, are you sure your view is producing markup?

Comment: I am getting HTTP 404: The resource cannot be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of opening `~/VidController/GetVids` in your browser you could try `/Vid/GetVids`. In ASP.NET MVC the standard convention is that the `Controller` suffix is used for the class name but removed when resolving the route.

When you call `VidController/GetVids`, the routing engine is trying to find a controller named  `VidControllerController` which obviously doesn't exist.